# Crear segunda hoja con PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Estoy trabajando con phpSpreadsheet para generar 2 informes

1. CARGA DIARIA
2. Clientes no registrados

Tengo problemas para añadir la segunda hoja del fichero. Al escribirse el fichero, la hoja1 queda con el nombre "Clientes no registrados" y la segunda con: "Worksheet" (nombre por defecto). como muestra la imágen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá el codigo que utilizo para crear la el excel:

```
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('CARGA DIARIA');
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $spreadsheet->getProperties()
            ->setCreator("Plataforma Company")
            ->setLastModifiedBy("Plataforma Company")
            ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX")
            ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Reporte")
            ->setDescription("Reporte Atraso Salida")
            ->setKeywords("Office 2007")
            ->setCategory("File");
    
    **PRIMERA PESTAÑA CLIENTES NO REGISTRADOS**
    $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $fil, 'Fecha Carga');
        $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $fil, 'Fecha Facturacion');
        $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $fil, 'Patente');
       ......## mas columnas ####

foreach($data...........
     $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $fil, $data['fecha_carga']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $fil, $data['fecha_facturacion']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $fil, $data['patente']);
        .....## mas columnas ####


**SEGUNDA PESTAÑA CLIENTES NO REGISTRADOS**
$spreadsheet->createSheet(1);
        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(1)
                ->setCellValue('A' . $fil, 'Fecha')
                ->setCellValue('B' . $fil, 'Cliente');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('CLIENTES NO REGISTRADOS');

foreach($response['response'] as $d => $data){
                $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(1)
                    ->setCellValue('A' . $fil, $data['fecha'])
                    ->setCellValue('B' . $fil, $data['cliente']);  
                $fil++;  
            }

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
###...... resto de lalógica ####
```

Agradecido de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera para cambiar el nombre de la segunda hoja

```php
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet($spreadsheet,"Hoja2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Para crear siguiente hoja
$hoja2 = $spreadsheet->createSheet();

// Generale el nombre de hoja para que confirmes que tienes la hoja creada
$hoja2->setTitle('Data');
```

'$hoja2' es una variable que yo cree

Comment: Gracias por editar no sabia como realizar la respuesta adecuadamente con el formato en código, soy nuevo en stackoverflow, saludos